# React/Typescript Storybook not allowing objects to be imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook

For whatever reason my storybook set up doesn't like object imports. Every-time import on object its undefined and gives me a TypeError.

> **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'news')). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

The file i am trying to import api.ts

```
interface Api {
  news: {
    getNews: Function;
  };
}

const api: Api = {
  news: {
    getNews: async (
      pageIndex?: number,
      pageSize?: number,
      featuredArticleId?: string,
      newsCategoryId?: string,
      type?: string,
      tag?: string,
    ) => {
      const { data }: AxiosResponse = await Axios.get(`${config.apiUrl}/news/listing`, {
        params: {
          newsCategoryId,
          pageIndex,
          pageSize,
          type,
          featuredArticleId,
          tag,
        },
      });
      return data;
    },
  },
};

export default api;
```

The React component looks something like this. When i log out the api it's always undefined.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import Reveal from 'react-reveal/Reveal';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import {
  Loader,
  Pagination,
  Dropdown,
  SectionHeading,
} from '../Common';
import { Container } from '../Helpers/Grid';
import FeaturedArticleCard from '../FeaturedNewsCard';
import NewsCard from '../NewsCard';
import NewsListProps from './type';
import NewsCardProps from '../NewsCard/type';
import getCurrentPage from '../Common/Pagination/getCurrentPage';
import api from '../../core/api/models';
import { NewsListApiResponse, Pagination as PaginationType } from '../../core/typings/api';
import { scrollIntoView, insertUrlParam } from '../../utilities/browser';
import './styles.scss';

console.log('api -> ', api);

interface FilterOption {
  displayText: string;
  value: string;
  selectedValue?: boolean;
}
// May need to come from the languages array
const defaultSelectedValue: string = 'all';

const NewsList = ({
  categories,
  featuredArticle,
  newsCategoryId,
  title,
  tag,
  noResultsText,
}: NewsListProps) => {
  const newsListItemsContainer = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);
  const [pageSize] = useState<number>(12);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState<FilterOption>(categories[0]);
  const [items, setItems] = useState<NewsCardProps[]>();
  const [apiError, setApiError] = useState<string>();
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState<PaginationType>();

  /**
   * Calls to news list api endpoint and updates state
   * accordingly
   * @param page
   */
  const fetchNews = async (page: number) => {
    const featuredArticleId = featuredArticle ? featuredArticle.id : undefined;
    const type = selectedFilter?.value !== defaultSelectedValue ? selectedFilter.value : undefined;
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const data: NewsListApiResponse = await api.news.getNews(
        page,
        pageSize,
        featuredArticleId,
        newsCategoryId,
        type,
        tag,
      );
      setItems(data.items);
      setPagination(data.pagination);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setApiError(error as string);
    }
  };

  /**
   * Pagination change action
   * @param page
   */
  const handlePage = (page: number) => {
    fetchNews(page);
    scrollIntoView(
      newsListItemsContainer?.current as HTMLUListElement,
      'smooth',
    );
  };

  /**
   * Updates the selected filter item from the jump list action
   * @param option
   */
  const filterByCategory = async (option: FilterOption) => {
    setSelectedFilter(option);
  };

  /**
   * Observes the selectedFilter state. If the state changes
   * and the value is not the default value it will call the
   * fetchNews method.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedFilter) {
      fetchNews(1);
      insertUrlParam('page', '1');
    }
  }, [selectedFilter]);

  /**
   * Inital actions on componentDidMount
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    // fetchNews(Number(getCurrentPage()));

    // We need to listen on popstate
    window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
      fetchNews(Number(getCurrentPage()));
    }, false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      <>
        {featuredArticle && (
          <div className="news-list-feature">
            <div className="news-list-feature__label">
              <h3>Featured</h3>
            </div>
            <Reveal effect="shortFadeInUp">
              <FeaturedArticleCard {...featuredArticle} />
            </Reveal>
          </div>
        )}

        <section className="news-list">
          {Boolean(!isLoading && items?.length) && (
            <div className="news-list__title">
              <SectionHeading text={title} />
            </div>
          )}

          <div className="news-list__container">
            {categories && (
              <div className="news-list__filters">
                <Dropdown
                  items={categories}
                  action={filterByCategory}
                  selectedValue={selectedFilter.value}
                  icon="icon-plus"
                  position="right"
                />
              </div>
            )}

            {apiError && (
              <div className="news-list__api-error">
                <h3>{apiError}</h3>
              </div>
            )}

            {Boolean(!items?.length && !isLoading) && (
              <div className="news-list__no-results">
                <h3>{noResultsText}</h3>
              </div>
            )}

            {isLoading && (
              <div className="news-list__loader">
                <Loader />
              </div>
            )}

            <ul ref={newsListItemsContainer} className="news-list__items">
              {Boolean(!isLoading && items?.length) && (
                <>
                  {items?.map((item, index) => (
                    <Reveal effect="shortFadeInUp" delay={index * 50}>
                      <li key={uuidv4()} className="news-list__item">
                        <NewsCard key={uuidv4()} {...item} />
                      </li>
                    </Reveal>

                  ))}
                </>
              )}
            </ul>

            {Boolean(pagination && items?.length) && (
              <nav className="news-list__pagination">
                <Pagination
                  totalItems={pagination?.totalItems as number}
                  currentPage={pagination?.currentPage as number}
                  itemsPerPage={pagination?.itemsPerPage as number}
                  handleClick={handlePage}
                />
              </nav>
            )}
          </div>
        </section>
      </>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default NewsList;
```

I am guessing this is probably something to do with the way i have set up the project? Not sure whats going on and why and i am only finding dead-end online.

Comment: Can you show how you use it in the component. Where do you access `news` ?

Comment: `setApiError(error as string);` how does error look like when you don't cast it?

Comment: Is it possible that the error is actually an object that you are trying to render as a string in your component?

Comment: Cannot believe this that was the issue i didn't even realise. I have been looking at this all day and thats all it was. 

thank you so much

Comment: Actually i am lying the api is still undefined but getting no TypeError now

Comment: So did it work? The problem is not that the API is undefined. (that causes an error but you catch that error) The main problem is that you then try to render the error inside your component. Does that make sense? Also please accept my answer when it works.

Comment: Sorry know it hasn't fixed the issue unfortunately the problem is 100% that api is undefined when it shouldn't be.

Comment: How does the `error` object look like?

Comment: If you remove the `setApiError(error as string);` function will it work?

Comment: I am trying to help you and I am 100 % sure that the API variable doesn't matter. The error that you are getting is from React when it tries to render something that it can't.